# Integration of Unity with Skype or other video messengers

Tags: video, unity-game-engine, integration, skype

Is there a way to integrate Unity with Skype or any other video messenger? I want Skype to get a videostream from Unity instead of getting it from camera. So that when I make a videocall, my interlocutor could see something rendered in Unity. In particular, is it possible on android/iOS devices? Thanks!

Comment: As far as i know skype has only web api for chat  (maybe video call as well, not sure). check out skype's developer page.

Answer (score 0):

On a PC (Windows and I think mac and linux, possibly android.) skype can do screen sharing so you can just run it in unity on your PC and stream that. [Here's the official tutorial on how to screen share using skype.](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10215/how-do-i-share-my-screen-in-skype-for-windows-desktop)

Comment: I know about this feature, but it is not what I want. I want user to be able to make a videocall, and then, for example, choose to use video stream provided by my application instead of using one from a camera, so you do not need to open any other apps.

Comment: I think you'd have to trick skype into thinking your stream is another screen or window then make them stream it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these http://www.magewell.com/usb-capture-hdmi-plus. Take the HDMI output off your video card plug it into the input side and your monitor into the loop thru.  Then plug the USB cable into an open USB 3.0 input in your computer.  The Magewell capture device will appear to the Windows OS as another webcam that you can choose as the device for Skype to stream.